# How to fix "Extra argument in call" error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to coding and am trying to have a selected image stored but it has an error saying "Extra argument in call." I'm not too sure what this means. What do I need to do? Thank you in advance!

```
@IBAction func shareButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
    view.endEditing(true)
    ProgressHUD.show("Waiting...", interaction: false)
    if let profileImg = self.selectedImage, let imageData = **selectedImage?.jpegData(profileImg, 0.1) {**
        let photoIdString = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOF_REF).child("posts").child(photoIdString)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the complete and exact error message and point out the exact line causing the issue.

Comment: This doesn't look right: `selectedImage?.jpegData(profileImg, 0.1)`

Comment: @Don Why is that incorrect? I'm trying to figure that out...

Comment: Try `let imageData = profileImg.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you see the code

> selectedImage?.jpegData(profileImg, 0.1)

you are passing two arguments. But, UIImage function, it takes only one argument which is the **compressionQuality**

[func jpegData(compressionQuality: CGFloat) -> Data?](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624115-jpegdata)

Answer (score 0):

"Extra argument in call" usually occurs when you pass incorrect parameters. `jpedData` accepts `compressionQuality` param.

Instead of `selectedImage?.jpegData(profileImg, 0.1)`

Try

> selectedImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1)